# Using PhoneGap, and adding an iAd

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

How would I use PhoneGap for my application, but keep my iAd's that I currently have in the new all HTML version of my application? I heard of an Ad plugin, but I could not find one. I am using iOS 6.0 for my SDK, and Cordova 2.1.0 for my PhoneGap Version.

I seen some old answers on here, but they all seem to be for iOS 4.0, and did not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the ad plugin here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/AdPlugin

In general, you can go here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins to browse all available plugins.